# Preprocessor Macro Explanation?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, c-preprocessor

My  teacher  is having us use the following preprocessor macro in implementing a linked queue in **C**. The idea is you make your queue generic by having it hold no data, then you have a wrapper struct elsewhere which holds the node in the queue, and the piece of data belonging to it.

The macro below takes in a node from the queue (i.e. node), the type of the wrapper struct (i.e. struct Wrapper), and name of the queue node element of the Wrapper (i.e. qnode (Wrapper has an element called qnode)).

Then the macro returns the struct Wrapper that the node passed in is contained in.

So a call would look like this:

```
queue_entry(node, struct Wrapper, qnode)
```

This is EXTREMELY COOL in my eyes, and it works fine, (seeing as how my teacher wrote it, it'd better!). 
But I was hoping someone could explain to me how it actually works? Because I'm at a loss for what is actually going on behind the scenes.

The Macro:

```
#define queue_entry(NODE, STRUCT, MEMBER)               \
    ((STRUCT *)((uint8_t*)(NODE) - offsetof(STRUCT, MEMBER)))
```

Comment: apparently he/she never learned that it is customary to capitalize macros, if you see it as a function and pass a parameter like i++ to a macro, bad things will happen

Comment: good to know!! Are we talking all caps?

Comment: Yes, macro names are conventionally written in `ALL_CAPS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member elements in C struct have fixed difference in their address. This difference gets defined at the compile time itself.

You can get this difference in address by using `&(struct_object.member) - &struct_object`. This is what is returned by `offsetof`.

e.g. consider below struct:

```
struct abcd{
int a; // 4 bytes
int b; // another 4 bytes
char c;// 1 byte
}
```

Then `offsetof(struct abcd,c)` would return 8. `offsetof(struct abcd,a)` would be 0 & so on. The '[padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding)' or 'alignment' within the struct also plays the role, in deciding the offset. However, this is decided at the compile time, not run time.

Hence, if you have address of a member (char c in our example), but not the structure, you can obtain the address of the parent structure, by subtracting the member address offset, from member address.

In your example, address of member is contained in node. Hence if you subtract member ofset, you will get address of container struct.

In linux kernel source code, same macro is available under the name, `container_of` (I forgot the capitalization & underscores if any).

Comment: makes perfect sense! Thanks for a great explanation.

Are you saying container_of does the same thing?

Comment: Nearly same, except that it takes member as argument rather than &member in your case.

Answer (score 1):

just think of macros as sed for C

any place where you see QUEUE_ENTRY(a, b, c) you would get:

((b *)((uint8_t*)(a) - offsetof(b, c)))

all of these replacements are done *before* it is ever compiled

Comment: so I've never used sed...I just know that it lets you edit text streams....

But lemme see if I understand what you're saying....

The macro goes in and replaces the references to QUEUE_ENTRY with the inner code, before run-time, and then that inner code just works arithmetically to be the pointer to the node that I want.

Comment: pretty much, its called a preprocessor. so if you have a macro `ABS(x) (x<0)?-x:x` and you used it like a function and passed index++, you would get `(index++<0)?-index++:index++` and the value of index was 6 when you passed it, then you would get 8 instead of the 6 that you would get if it were a function.  Thus the importance of distinguishing them with caps. A compile is actually 4 parts - preprocess .c and .h to intermediate .i files, compile the .i files into .s assembly files and then assemble the .s files into .o object files ... finally link the .o files into .so library or binary